# MySQL: How to get the change in price from history table?

Tags: mysql

This is my simplified history table structure:

```
id | property_id | price   | created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at
1  |      1      |   100   | 2016-04-10 01:00:00 | 2016-04-10 01:00:00 | NULL
2  |      1      |   300   | 2016-04-10 01:00:00 | 2016-04-10 01:00:00 | NULL
3  |      1      |   300   | 2016-04-10 02:00:00 | 2016-04-10 02:00:00 | NULL
4  |      2      |   200   | 2016-04-10 03:00:00 | 2016-04-10 03:00:00 | NULL
1  |      2      |   150   | 2016-04-10 04:00:00 | 2016-04-10 04:00:00 | NULL
```

1. i want to get the records that meet a certain criteria, particularly that the `created_at` field is within the last 24 hours
2. i need to get the record that immediately precedes the records in #1
3. further filter results in #1 to records whose `price` column has had a different value in a record's history, other than -1

Im really having problem in #2 and #3 especially filtering the results. I don't want to do it via looping the #1 results because I have a lot of data and it will take so much time to do it. Any one can help me to do it in one query?

Comment: My answer starts with a question:  Is the most current price stored in the history table?

Comment: Yes. The last inserted property_id has the current price.

Answer (score 2):

What comes to mind is a correlated subquery to get the previous price.  The following version uses a `having` clause for the final comparison (a subquery could also be used):

```
select h.*,
       (select h2.price
        from history h2
        where h2.property_id = h.property_id and
              h2.created_at < h.created_at
        order by h2.created_at desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_price
from history h
where h.created_at > date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)
having prev_price is null or prev_price <> price;
```

For performance, you want indexes on `history(created_at)` and `history(property_id, created_at, price)`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try

Comment: The problem you may find is that without making sure that the nested query is ordered correctly, LIMIT 1 may present you with an answer other than that which you are asking for.  From a performance perspective, an inline correlated subquery in a select usually takes a performance hit.  YMMV

Comment: @TGray . . . I'm not sure what you are referring to.  The subquery has an `order by` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's still slow after adding the indexes. I have about a million data in history.

Comment: Because of the "h.created_at > date_sub..." it won't use an index on created_at.  The "is null or prev_price <> price" is also an index killer.  The first part "is null" means "don't use an index" because NULL rows are not represented in an index.

Comment: @TGray . . . Your understanding of indexes is flawed regarding the subquery.  A good place to start is the documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).  As for the `having` clause, there may be no occasion where MySQL will use an index for it (and I certainly don't claim that there is a way to build an index in this case).

Comment: Not really.  At best, assuming that property_id is the leading column in  a concatenated index, it will do a partial table scan based on the non-equality operator in the second clause.  If the property_id is not the leading column, it will not use the index.  In the event that there are non-concatenated indexes on those columns, it will use the property_id index but still do a partial scan against the result set.

Comment: What do you think about this query? `SELECT * FROM history t1 WHERE t1.created_at >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) AND (SELECT t2.price FROM history t2 WHERE t2.property_id = t1.property_id AND t2.created_at < t1.created_at ORDER BY DATE(t2.created_at) DESC LIMIT 1) <> t1.price` The idea is still the same. Seems like this is a bit faster than the above.

Comment: @KelvinMartinLigue . . . Moving the condition to the `WHERE` probably is faster.